# Form panel not showing by set active item

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

Am new to sencha touch, my problem is i have a separate view to show a form panel by clicking on control event the form panel view will load, but when i click on the event nothing display on my screen. Just a blank screen to show..I dont know what am doing. The form panel is taken from sencha form panel tutorial

The following are my form panel view

```
Ext.define('WinReo.view.AddContact', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'addcontact',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar'
        //'Ext.Video'
    ],
    config: {
        layout:'fit'

    },
    initialize:function(){
        console.log('inside initialize');
        var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            //xytpe:'formpanel',
            fullscreen: true,
            layout:'fit',

            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name : 'name',
                        label: 'Name'

                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'emailfield',
                        name : 'email',
                        label: 'Email'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                        name : 'password',
                        label: 'Password'
                    }
                ]
            }]
        });

        formPanel.add({
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'bottom',
            layout: { pack: 'center' },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Set Data',
                    handler: function() {
                        formPanel.setValues({
                            name: 'Ed',
                            email: 'ed@sencha.com',
                            password: 'secret'
                        })
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Get Data',
                    handler: function() {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Form Values', JSON.stringify(formPanel.getValues(), null, 2));
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Clear Data',
                    handler: function() {
                        formPanel.reset();
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

    }
});
```

This is the controller event to show form panel view

```
    onItemSwiped: function(list,index,target,record,e)
        {
var addcontact= Ext.create('WinReo.view.AddContact');
            Ext.Viewport.add(addcontact);
            Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(addcontact);
        },
```

Just a simple task but am spending too much time to fix this one..please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance..

Comment: try to set formpanel flex value to 1 and see what happens, also let me know if you getting any error

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i tried this way
 var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            flex:1,
            ........
but its not working..not getting any error in my console..

Actually the form is there when i give formPanel.show(); command at the end of the form i can see the bottom tool bar buttons but the text fileds are not visible. when i click the set data and get data buttons i can see the popup data. the only problem is the text field  is hidden..thanks in advance plz help to solve this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your right about setActiveItem and you need to use it.  because Ext.Viewport.add() only adds to viewPort not shows the view.

So only problem in your code is you created formPanel, but not added it in the AddContact  View.

```
    ........... 
    // same code
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Get Data',
                    handler: function() {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Form Values', JSON.stringify(formPanel.getValues(), null, 2));
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Clear Data',
                    handler: function() {
                        formPanel.reset();
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        this.add(formPanel); // add this line
    }
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#fjrAI)

Comment: thanks for this quick reply.. i removed the Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(addcontact);..then the page navigation is not taking place. The window is not showing the AddContact view. The event is working but active item is still the current page.. I dont know what am doing wrong.. Normally i did page navidation using these three lines of code 

var addcontact= Ext.create('WinReo.view.AddContact');
            Ext.Viewport.add(addcontact);
            Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(addcontact);

Comment: Thank you so much Viswa....you are awesome....now its working fyn...thanks a lot dear...